# Incorrect character displacement obtained using PoDoFo

Tags: c++, pdf, fonts, podofo

I'm using PoDoFo to extract character displacement to update a text matrix correctly. This is a code fragment of mine:

```
PdfString str, ucode_str;
std::stack<PdfVariant> *stack;
const PdfFontMetrics *f_metrics;
...

/* Convert string to UTF8 */
str = stack->top().GetString();
ucode_str = ts->font->GetEncoding()->ConvertToUnicode(str, ts->font);
stack->pop();
c_str = (char *) ucode_str.GetStringUtf8().c_str();

/* Font metrics to obtain a character displacement */
f_metrics = ts->font->GetFontMetrics();

for (j = 0; j < strlen(c_str); j++) {
    str_w = f_metrics->CharWidth(c_str[j]);

    /* Adjust text matrix using str_w */
    ...
}
```

It works well for some PDF files (`str_w` contains a useful width), but doesn't work for others. In these cases `str_w` contains `0.0`. I took a look at the PoDoFo `0.9.5` sources and found `CharWidth()` implemented for all sub-classes of `PdfFontMetrics`.

Am I missing something important during this string conversion?

**Update from 04.08.2017**

@mkl did a really good job reviewing PoDoFo's code. However, I realized that I had to obtain a bit different parameter. To be precise, I needed a *glyph width* expressed in *text space units* (see [PDF Reference 1.7](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf), *5.1.3 Glyph Positioning and Metrics*), but `CharWidth()` is implemented in `PdfFontMetricsObject.cpp` like:

```
double PdfFontMetricsObject::CharWidth(unsigned char c) const
{
    if (c >= m_nFirst && c <= m_nLast &&
        c - m_nFirst < static_cast<int>(m_width.GetSize())) {
        double dWidth = m_width[c - m_nFirst].GetReal();

        return (dWidth * m_matrix.front().GetReal() * this->GetFontSize() + this->GetFontCharSpace()) * this->GetFontScale() / 100.0;
    }

    if (m_missingWidth != NULL)
        return m_missingWidth->GetReal();
    else
        return m_dDefWidth;
}
```

Width is calculated using additional multipliers (like font size, character space, etc.). What I really needed was `dWidth * m_matrix.front().GetReal()` only. Thus, I decided to implement `GetGlyphWidth(int c)` from the same file like:

```
double PdfFontMetricsObject::GetGlyphWidth(int c) const
{
    if (c >= m_nFirst && c <= m_nLast &&
        c - m_nFirst < static_cast<int>(m_width.GetSize())) {
        double dWidth = m_width[c - m_nFirst].GetReal();
        return dWidth * m_matrix.front().GetReal();
    }
    return 0.0;
}
```

and call this one instead of `CharWidth()` from the first listing.

Comment: Please share a sample PDF for analysis. There are some very weird PDFs in which all glyph widths indeed are 0 and the text matrix is moved along by separate instructions. Probably you have such a file.

Comment: [This PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5bUjbiZdo9nVFlQVFNNWHpBaVE/view?usp=sharing) is processed with error (displacement is `0.0`)

Comment: [This one](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1fFjmlHIxF2T2twUTNLTmRmVWM/view?usp=sharing) is correctly processed (I'm interested in first page only)

Comment: @mkl, do you mean something like `[ (A) 120 (W) 120 (A) 95 (Y again) ] TJ`? I thought that these characters should have the correct displacements, also.

Comment: *" do you mean something like ... I thought that these characters should have the correct displacements, also."* - Yes, they *should* have the correct displacement and the values in **TJ** are only to be used for kerning; but there indeed are some PDFs out there in which the numbers in **TJ** do the whole displacement. But this is not the issue in case of your sample PDF, cf. my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the Podofo code correctly (I'm not really a Podofo expert...), the `PdfFontMetricsObject` class is used to represent the metrics of fonts contained in an already existing PDF:

```
/** Create a font metrics object based on an existing PdfObject
 *
 *  \param pObject an existing font descriptor object
 *  \param pEncoding a PdfEncoding which will NOT be owned by PdfFontMetricsObject
 */
PdfFontMetricsObject( PdfObject* pFont, PdfObject* pDescriptor, const PdfEncoding* const pEncoding );
```

The method `CharWidth` here is implemented like this:

```
double PdfFontMetricsObject::CharWidth( unsigned char c ) const
{
    if( c >= m_nFirst && c <= m_nLast
        && c - m_nFirst < static_cast<int>(m_width.GetSize()) )
    {
        double dWidth = m_width[c - m_nFirst].GetReal();

        return (dWidth * m_matrix.front().GetReal() * this->GetFontSize() + this->GetFontCharSpace()) * this->GetFontScale() / 100.0;
    }

    if( m_missingWidth != NULL )
        return m_missingWidth->GetReal ();
    else
        return m_dDefWidth;
}
```

One in particular sees that the parameter `c` is not encoded according to the font encoding but left as is for the lookup in the widths array. Thus, the expected input of this method does not appear to be a ASCII or ANSI character code but the original glyph ID.

Your code, on the other hand, has already transformed the glyph IDs to Unicode in UTF-8 and, therefore, essentially tries to lookup by ANSI character codes.

---

This would match the example documents, a typical font encoding in the PDF processed with error looks like this

```
28 0 obj
<<
  /Differences[0/B/G/W/a/d/e/f/g  9/i/l/n/o/p/r/space/t/w]
  /BaseEncoding/MacRomanEncoding
  /Type/Encoding
>>
endobj
```

with glyph codes from 0 (**FirstChar**) to 17 (**LastChar**), or

```
12 0 obj
<<
  /Differences[1/A/B/C/D/F/I/L/M/N/O/P/R/T/U/a/c/d
                /degree/e/eight/f/five/four/g/h
               27/i/l/m/n/o/one/p/parenleft/parenright
                /period/r/registered/s/space
                /t/three/two/u/w/zero]
  /BaseEncoding/MacRomanEncoding
  /Type/Encoding
>>
endobj
```

with glyph codes from 1 (**FirstChar**) to 46 (**LastChar**).

So these encoding deal glyph codes starting from 0 for all required glyphs and don't really cover that many glyphs

Thus, `CharWidth` will return `0` for all char values above 17 or above 46 which means all (in the former case) or most (in the latter case) ANSI non control characters.

On the other hand a typical font encoding in the PDF processed correctly looks like this:

```
1511 0 obj
<<
  /Type/Encoding
  /BaseEncoding/WinAnsiEncoding
  /Differences[
    1/Delta/Theta
    8/Phi
    11/ff/fi/fl/ffi
    39/quoteright
  ]
>>
endobj
```

with glyph codes from 1 (**FirstChar**) to 122 (**LastChar**).

These encodings basically are **WinAnsiEncoding** with minor additions in the lower values, in particular the control character values.

---

What you can do, therefore, is to iterate over glyph codes in `str` (allowing you to call `CharWidth` for them) and converting them individually to Unicode when needed instead of first converting `str` to Unicode `ucode_str` and then iterating over ANSI characters in `ucode_str`.

Comment: @DmitrySalychev Great! Admittedly I wrote the answer without testing my proposal, merely based on Podofo code review, so I'm happy, too, that my analysis was right.